# Nginx.conf overwriting?

Tags: nginx

We recently setup a Nginx Server and even if Nginx themselves say that users should place their configs in the subfolder `conf.d`, we decided to not do so.

First and mainly because one does not know how multiple instances would overwrite themself and in what order they would be loaded.

So we took the `nginx.conf`, cleaned it up and put our stuff in there. It works that's not a problem... I'm just questioning myself if (in the past) `nginx` anytime updated the `nginx.conf` with one of there updates?

That would be a bummer for us. I can't believe that this would happen but maybe you guys have had this situation that the default `nginx.conf` was updated in the past. Then this information would be quite interessing for me.

If not i'm also happy :)

Answer (score 2):

It should be pretty safe to do what you did.

*Usually*, when an Ubuntu update needs to replace a configuration file, it detects if the file has been modified and asks you what it should do.

You can then choose to keep *your* version, and then the updater creates a *new* configuration file with extension `.dkpg-dist` which contains the (updated) configuration for the new package version (in your case `nginx.conf.dpkg-dist`).

You can then easily check which are the differences between the *new* config file and *your custom one* and decide if you want to incorporate them (usually a good idea to keep current with new defaults, security fixes, etc).

You can also choose to instead install the *new* version, or maybe some kind of option/default you use forces the "overwrite" without asking, but even then your customizations are not lost.

You'll find a `nginx.conf.dpkg-old` which contains a backup of *your* `nginx.conf` before the upgrader "overwrote" the configuration.